# how i can fix the Health Analyzer's Configuration problem "Missing server side dependencies"

Tags: 2013, development, central-administration, administration, health-analyzer

I am working on SharePoint server 2013 enterprise , and i run the Health Analyzer, but i got this error "Missing server side dependencies" as shown below:-
[image]

and here is the full description of the problem , when i click on the above error:-

```
[MissingFeature] Database [WSS_Content_ea05119bb8a4408ab450dcd46d6015e8] has reference(s) to a missing feature: Id = [cf028f31-828e-4eed-974a-0348f13e417b]. The feature with Id cf028f31-828e-4eed-974a-0348f13e417b is referenced in the database [WSS_Content_ea05119bb8a4408ab450dcd46d6015e8], but is not installed on the current farm. The missing feature may cause upgrade to fail. Please install any solution which contains the feature and restart upgrade if necessary.
[MissingFeature] Database [WSS_Content_ea05119bb8a4408ab450dcd46d6015e8] has reference(s) to a missing feature: Id = [52b02d90-4458-4976-a15b-0a8101b296fd]. The feature with Id 52b02d90-4458-4976-a15b-0a8101b296fd is referenced in the database [WSS_Content_ea05119bb8a4408ab450dcd46d6015e8], but is not installed on the current farm. The missing feature may cause upgrade to fail. Please install any solution which contains the feature and restart upgrade if necessary.
[MissingFeature] Database [WSS_Content_ea05119bb8a4408ab450dcd46d6015e8] has reference(s) to a missing feature: Id = [745612e7-780e-4cc8-a1fb-0e73b891e93e]. The feature with Id 745612e7-780e-4cc8-a1fb-0e73b891e93e is referenced in the database [WSS_Content_ea05119bb8a4408ab450dcd46d6015e8], but is not installed on the current farm. The missing feature may cause upgrade to fail. Please install any solution which contains the feature and restart upgrade if necessary.
[MissingFeature] Database [WSS_Content_ea05119bb8a4408ab450dcd46d6015e8] has reference(s) to a missing feature: Id = [2bd78eb6-3060-47fa-8ee7-2733473960ce]. The feature with Id 2bd78eb6-3060-47fa-8ee7-2733473960ce is referenced in the database [WSS_Content_ea05119bb8a4408ab450dcd46d6015e8], but is not installed on the current farm. The missing feature may cause upgrade to fail. Please install any solution which contains the feature and restart upgrade if necessary.
[MissingFeature] Database [WSS_Content_ea05119bb8a4408ab450dcd46d6015e8] has reference(s) to a missing feature: Id = [abb49f6d-eb80-4668-a012-3fc9ced16cd2]. The feature with Id abb49f6d-eb80-4668-a012-3fc9ced16cd2 is referenced in the database [WSS_Content_ea05119bb8a4408ab450dcd46d6015e8], but is not installed on the current farm. The missing feature may cause upgrade to fail. Please install any solution which contains the feature and restart upgrade if necessary.
[MissingFeature] Database [WSS_Content_ea05119bb8a4408ab450dcd46d6015e8] has reference(s) to a missing feature: Id = [d10cfb86-2134-4b65-a565-4a205678c38a]. The feature with Id d10cfb86-2134-4b65-a565-4a205678c38a is referenced in the database [WSS_Content_ea05119bb8a4408ab450dcd46d6015e8], but is not installed on the current farm. The missing feature may cause upgrade to fail. Please install any solution which contains the feature and restart upgrade if necessary.
[MissingFeature] Database [WSS_Content_ea05119bb8a4408ab450dcd46d6015e8] has reference(s) to a missing feature: Id = [427741e7-6206-48ff-9f4c-53ffddda7f7d]. The feature with Id 427741e7-6206-48ff-9f4c-53ffddda7f7d is referenced in the database [WSS_Content_ea05119bb8a4408ab450dcd46d6015e8], but is not installed on the current farm. The missing feature may cause upgrade to fail. Please install any solution which contains the feature and restart upgrade if necessary.
[MissingFeature] Database [WSS_Content_ea05119bb8a4408ab450dcd46d6015e8] has reference(s) to a missing feature: Id = [52e03d0d-b7bd-4361-9dae-78e935776f87]. The feature with Id 52e03d0d-b7bd-4361-9dae-78e935776f87 is referenced in the database [WSS_Content_ea05119bb8a4408ab450dcd46d6015e8], but is not installed on the current farm. The missing feature may cause upgrade to fail. Please install any solution which contains the feature and restart upgrade if necessary.
[MissingFeature] Database [WSS_Content_ea05119bb8a4408ab450dcd46d6015e8] has reference(s) to a missing feature: Id = [2447a60d-aa93-4a9a-b4f5-7edc58fa983b]. The feature with Id 2447a60d-aa93-4a9a-b4f5-7edc58fa983b is referenced in the database [WSS_Content_ea05119bb8a4408ab450dcd46d6015e8], but is not installed on the current farm. The missing feature may cause upgrade to fail. Please install any solution which contains the feature and restart upgrade if necessary.
[MissingFeature] Database [WSS_Content_ea05119bb8a4408ab450dcd46d6015e8] has reference(s) to a missing feature: Id = [78f75040-d941-4ad4-8ec8-be2991e4dd05]. The feature with Id 78f75040-d941-4ad4-8ec8-be2991e4dd05 is referenced in the database [WSS_Content_ea05119bb8a4408ab450dcd46d6015e8], but is not installed on the current farm. The missing feature may cause upgrade to fail. Please install any solution which contains the feature and restart upgrade if necessary.
[MissingFeature] Database [WSS_Content_ea05119bb8a4408ab450dcd46d6015e8] has reference(s) to a missing feature: Id = [0eb3b42e-78ca-4ccd-b26f-c9d9f4d76ffb]. The feature with Id 0eb3b42e-78ca-4ccd-b26f-c9d9f4d76ffb is referenced in the database [WSS_Content_ea05119bb8a4408ab450dcd46d6015e8], but is not installed on the current farm. The missing feature may cause upgrade to fail. Please install any solution which contains the feature and restart upgrade if necessary.
[MissingFeature] Database [WSS_Content_ea05119bb8a4408ab450dcd46d6015e8] has reference(s) to a missing feature: Id = [6b46c207-5c7d-44ad-b0d4-f4682557a85b]. The feature with Id 6b46c207-5c7d-44ad-b0d4-f4682557a85b is referenced in the database [WSS_Content_ea05119bb8a4408ab450dcd46d6015e8], but is not installed on the current farm. The missing feature may cause upgrade to fail. Please install any solution which contains the feature and restart upgrade if necessary.
[MissingFeature] Database [WSS_Content_ea05119bb8a4408ab450dcd46d6015e8] has reference(s) to a missing feature: Id = [d74427d2-ac0d-45e6-af53-f67dab3beb2e]. The feature with Id d74427d2-ac0d-45e6-af53-f67dab3beb2e is referenced in the database [WSS_Content_ea05119bb8a4408ab450dcd46d6015e8], but is not installed on the current farm. The missing feature may cause upgrade to fail. Please install any solution which contains the feature and restart upgrade if necessary.

[MissingFeature] Database [SharePoint_AdminContent_dcd6a143-52e3-4b8a-b11b-d96a24b62b0a] has reference(s) to a missing feature: Id = [0eb3b42e-78ca-4ccd-b26f-c9d9f4d76ffb], Name = [WikiKnowledgeBaseRedirect Feature1], Description = [My Visual Web Part Feature], Install Location = [WikiKnowledgeBaseRedirect_Feature1]. The feature with Id 0eb3b42e-78ca-4ccd-b26f-c9d9f4d76ffb is referenced in the database [SharePoint_AdminContent_dcd6a143-52e3-4b8a-b11b-d96a24b62b0a], but is not installed on the current farm. The missing feature may cause upgrade to fail. Please install any solution which contains the feature and restart upgrade if necessary.
[MissingSetupFile] File [Features\WikiKnowledgeBaseRedirect_Feature1\VisualWebPart1\VisualWebPart1.webpart] is referenced [1] times in the database [SharePoint_AdminContent_dcd6a143-52e3-4b8a-b11b-d96a24b62b0a], but is not installed on the current farm. Please install any feature/solution which contains this file. One or more setup files are referenced in the database [SharePoint_AdminContent_dcd6a143-52e3-4b8a-b11b-d96a24b62b0a], but are not installed on the current farm. Please install any feature or solution which contains these files.
```

so from the error seems there are missing features inside our content database, so can anyone advice how i can find these features and how i can remove them??.. but at the same time we are not facing any problem inside our farm,, so not sure how sever are these errors ?

Answer (score 1):

The SharePoint Feature Administration and Clean Up Tool available at http://featureadmin.codeplex.com/ usually does a good job of cleaning these up.

I usually use the script at http://etienne-sharepoint.blogspot.co.uk/2011/10/solving-missingsetupfile-errors-from.html to deal with missing setup file issues (just remember to add the $file.delete() line when you want to actually remove the references).

Andy

Comment: thanks for the reply,, but do you have any idea what can cause these features to be displayed in the error? from the link you provide it mentioned that those features might got displayed after migrating from 2010 to 2013,, but in my case i did not migrate from 2010 ... the only feature i might have installed is "WikiKnowledgeBaseRedirect Feature1",, but the other i do not know what they are exactly ?

Comment: As you say, usually these are the result of a solution being installed and deployed into the database referenced, then the solution is removed without removing the instances within a site collection that have been used.

Comment: If someone has manually hacked features onto the farm (e.g. by manually adding them to the features folder in the SharePoint hive), then removed them, this can also happen.
You can do a search for the GUIDs shown above to see if they are referenced anywhere, e.g. the GUID 52b02d90-4458-4976-a15b-0a8101b296fd appears to be a Bamboo solution called "Bamboo.GroupRedirect.WebPart".

Answer (score 0):

An explanation why this happens and how to solve it can be found here:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/dawiese/post-upgrade-cleanup-missing-server-side-dependencies

The powershell script is:

```
$featureID = "xxx"
$siteID = "xxx"

#Display site information
$site = Get-SPSite $siteID
Write-Host "Checking Site:" $site.Url

#Remove the feature from all subsites
ForEach ($web in $Site.AllWebs) {
  If($web.Features[$featureID]) {
    Write-Host "`nFound Feature $featureID in web:"$Web.Url"`nRemoving feature"
    $web.Features.Remove($featureID, $true)
  } else {
    Write-Host "`nDid not find feature $featureID in web:" $Web.Url
  }
}

#Remove the feature from the site collection
If ($Site.Features[$featureID]) {
  Write-Host "`nFound feature $featureID in site:"$site.Url"`nRemoving Feature"
  $site.Features.Remove($featureID, $true)
} else {
  Write-Host "Did not find feature $featureID in site:" $site.Url
}
```